# How can I get this link while parsing JSON?

Tags: json

I've been trying to get the mobile link from this API but I haven't been successful

```
.done(function( data ) {    
                var ol = $("<ol/>");

            $.each( data.headlines, function(h_key, headlines) {
var h2 = $( "<h2/>" ).append(headlines.headline);
 var a = $( "<a/>" ).attr("href", headlines.links.mobile);

ol.append(h2)
 ol.append(a)
```

This is the response body I'm trying to get the link from

```
{
"timestamp": "2013-10-21T14:50:18Z",
"resultsOffset": 0,
"status": "success",
"resultsLimit": 10,
"resultsCount": 27,
"headlines": [{
    "headline": "Portugal land Sweden in playoff draw",
    "keywords": ["UEFA WCQ: Portugal land Sweden in playoff draw"],
    "lastModified": "2013-10-21T14:17:13Z",
    "audio": [],
    "premium": false,
    "mobileStory": "",
    "links": {
        "api": {
            "news": {
                "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/1588808?region=GB"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "http://espnfc.com/news/story/_/id/1588808/portugal-land-sweden-playoff-draw?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
        },
        "mobile": {
            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/soccer/story?storyId=1588808&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
        }
    },
```

Comment: `headlines.links.mobile.href`, no?

Answer (score 1):

`headlines` is an array.  Also, `mobile` still has another component to drill down into.  Try this:

```
headlines[0].links.mobile.href
```

You'll probably want to add some runtime checking to make sure there's an element in `headlines` before you index it, of course.

A good way to test things like this is in your browser debugging tools.  Usually you can put a break point in the debugger and see the structure of the JSON object.  Some quick trial-and-error of referencing components of that object on the JavaScript console will help you navigate its structure.

**Edit:** I just noticed that you're iterating the array, so more likely:

```
headlines.links.mobile.href
```

You might want to change the name of your iterator variable from `headlines` as it may cause confusion.  `headline` seems like a sensible alternative.

Comment: it worked but the output was in text format instead of a link. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2902458: What do you mean by "the output was in text format"?  The data itself is just text.  It's only a "link" when it's set as the `href` attribute for an `a` tag, which it looks like you're doing.  Does that `a` tag not work as expected?  What is the structure of that `a` tag after this code modifies it?

Comment: the a tag works, the issue is that I want a situation where when the "link" is clicked it opens that web page so you can read the story. Do you get my point? Sorry for confusing you

Comment: even with the a tag it's still pure text, is it possible to output as a link?

Comment: @user2902458: You're not being very clear about the problem, I'm afraid.  What is the *actual* structure of the `a` tag after this code executes?  Currently you're just trying to describe the tag, when it would make more sense to just copy and paste the actual tag itself so I can see it.

Comment: `var a =  $( "<a/>" ).append("href",headlines.links.mobile.href);`

Comment: I got this as the output of the code above, what I actually want is a click-able hyper-link    _hrefhttp://m.espn.go.com/soccer/story?storyId=1588808&ex_cid=espnapi_public_

Comment: @user2902458 you were using `.attr` in the question, now you are using `.append` That's your trouble.

Comment: @user2902458: Why did you change it to use `.append()`?  You want to set the `href` attribute, not write text.  If you look at the actual `a` tag being rendered you'll see that you have `<a>somelink</a>` when what you want is `<a href="somelink">sometext</a>`.  You need to set the `href` attribute to the link, and then include some text to be clickable.

Comment: @David finally figured it out. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
var h2 = $( "<h2/>" ).append(headlines[0].headline);
var a = $( "<a/>" ).attr("href", headlines[0].links.mobile.href);
```